# How to change list item data when clicked on a sub view

Tags: android, listadapter

```
holder.voteUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = myList.getPositionForView((View) v
                .getParent());
        final ListItem li  = values.get(position);
        li.voteUp_value = true;
        //In getView(), I set different image to holder.voteUp ImageView depending on this value.
        //Hence I call notifyDataSetChanged(); which takes care of it.
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

But the problem is, Since the whole list is notified, it flickers every time I vote.

I cannot changed the Image of the `holder.voteUp` directly, because there is a `holder.voteDown` which has to be changed too, depending on the `li.voteUp_value`. So, I went with `notifyDataSetChanged();` which takes care of all this.

Is there a way I can get the Views from parent View and set the Images, instead of `notifyDataSetChanged();`?

**like:**

```
ViewParent vp = v.getParent();
ImageView im = vp.findViewById(R.id.voteUp);
im.setImageResource.....
```

But there is nothing like `findViewById` for `ViewParent`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the view passed to you from the `onClick()` listener. Just changing the image should be enough to make it redraw, but if not you can still tell it to manually.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final int position = myList.getPositionForView((View) v
            .getParent());
    final ListItem li  = values.get(position);
    li.voteUp_value = true;

    ImageView im = vp.findViewById(R.id.voteUp);
    if ( im != null ) {
        //Update the view here
    }
}
```